# smarty assinging variable

Tags: php, smarty, templating, task-parallel-library

I am trying to assing a variable in my .tpl by doing this,

```
{assign var="image" value="images/stores/{$location.storename|regex_replace:"/[' ']/":"-"|lower}.jpg"}
```

however I am getting this error,

> Smarty error: [in stores/view-store.tpl line 135]: syntax error: invalid attribute name: '|lower'

How Can i stop this error but still drop the casing of the returned info to lowercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you take lower off you're still going to have problems.  You can't have a {} block inside a {} block. Nor can you have "" nested in "".

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.custom.functions.tpl#language.function.assign

Look at that page, check out the complex example.  You'll use something like

```
{assign var="image" value=``}
```

This might also be useful for you:

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.eval.tpl

Ultimately though, you should be doing that on the PHP side, logic and code is not meant to be in the template unless there really is no other choice.